# Taking content from comments in my answer

Tags: discussion, comments

I answer a fair amount of new questions in popular tags (mostly [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)), and frequently face this (more ethical than technical) issue:

While I am writing a long and detailed answer, some people come at the same time and add simple improvements to OP's problems as comments (be they code typo fixes, memory management advice or links to answers that solve part of the problem).

Although my answer has more info and research, and is more explicit, it also benefits from those people's perspective.
Should I simply tag them in the answer?

> as said by @thisGuy in the comments above

Or should I make my answer a Community wiki?

Comment: Note that using `@` in an answer is meaningless (except for the mental connection with tagging). More commonly, people link to the user's profile or the respective comment (assuming it still exists...)

Comment: Ultimately it's up to you, some users prefer CW because they don't feel they earned the rep when they're just copying someones comment. Others post as proper answers because that's what the comment author should've done in the first place

Comment: @Tomerikoo You can link to a comment?

Comment: Right-click the timestamp of a comment and copy the link

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know that

Comment: @bad_coder I think this question can stand on its own

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to make your answer a Community Wiki; after all, you put effort into writing the answer, and deserve credit for it in terms of any reputation gain (or loss, if the answer is not useful).

While it's not *required* to attribute the comments, in my opinion it's definitely a good idea to do that whenever possible. After all, you were helped by the comments, and the user who posted the comments should get credit for that as well.

You could simply mention the comment in your answer, as you point out, by writing "@username". However, simply mentioning the username means that the attribution is not clear if the user decides to change their username. Similarly, though this happens less often, the username might be a common one, and there may be multiple users with that username who've commented on the post.

I would suggest explicitly linking to the user's profile. This way the attribution works even if the username changes. Also, you could link to the comment itself; the "timestamp" button next to a comment is actually a hyperlink to the comment itself. So you could write something like:

> In response to the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405447/taking-content-from-comments-in-my-answer#comment826371_405447) by [Adalcar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5036612):
>
> > You can link to a comment?
>
> Yes, you can link to a comment.

I would also quote the comment verbatim in your answer, as I just did in the demonstration, as comments are second class citizens, and are subject to be deleted at any time.

Comment: While I completely agree with this answer I would say that we should do it only when we are actually quoting the comment in full. If you are merely using ideas from other people's comment to write your own answer then you are not plagiarising anything IMHO. Adding thanks in such situations could be perceived as unnecessary noise to an observer that comes some time later when the comments are all deleted.

Comment: If there's a substantive comment from a user that I incorporate into my answer (because I hadn't noted the issue mentally before seeing the comment), then I use two links, one to the user and one to the comment. If I'm confident that I had the comment fully in mind before I saw it, I will sometimes use "as also noted by User in comment", still giving credit for also thinking of the issue, but not that they were the only person to think of the issue (though they must have been quicker than me to record it, but that is because I'm taking longer to write a complete answer than they are).

Answer (score 3):

As long as the answer is still substantially yours, there is nothing wrong with adding information from the comments or quoting comments in your own answer. If you find something in the comments that should have been an answer, and you want to copy and paste it mostly verbatim as an answer, make it a community wiki.

I sometimes find myself adding the following in the middle of my answers:

as <insert username> pointed out, ...

Here are a few cases that I think are more definitive for when you should or should not provide credit:

Don't give credit when

- A comment mentions some documentation or general piece of knowledge. Feel free to steal that idea and turn it into a full answer.

Provide credit when

- You quote a comment or use a non-obvious code snippet. (An obvious code snippet being something like *use `list.remove()`*.)
- There is or could be disagreement, and you want to provide more authority to what you are saying.

In general, just make sure it doesn't look like you are just copying and pasting comments as your own answer to try to get reputation.